# error 0x80070005: Adding a tile failed with unexpected error running WACK on Jenkins

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins, wack

Getting "error 0x80070005: Adding a tile failed with unexpected error" here while trying to run appcert (WACK) on an application that is NOT installed within a Jenkins session executing a Windows batch command.  I've written a simple C# wrapper to call appcert in elevated user mode.  Wrapper and basic command line work outside of Jenkins on the same box in an unelevated cmd window... scratching head...

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit\appcert.exe" reset

if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /b %errorlevel%

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit\appcert.exe" test -appxpackagepath %WORKSPACE%\UWP_0.9.%BUILD_NUMBER%.0_x86_x64_arm.appxbundle -reportoutputpath %WORKSPACE%\wack.xml

if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /b %errorlevel%



16:32:04 Successfully reset the testing configuration.

16:32:11     Beginning execution of task Detect app type from package.

16:32:11     Task Detect app type from package execution result was success.

16:32:11     Note: Test application type - UapApp.

16:32:11     Beginning execution of task Extract files from package.

16:32:11     Beginning execution of task Performs AppX deployment/cleanup in the IDE scenario..

16:32:11     Task Extract files from package execution result was success.

16:32:11 Root "Trusted Root Certification Authorities"

16:32:11 Signature matches Public Key

16:32:11 Related Certificates:

16:32:11 

16:32:11 Exact match:

16:32:11 Element 7:

16:32:11 Serial Number: 1b659911670d2b9f436f7b922e12ed51

16:32:11 Issuer: CN=ED346674-0FA1-4272-85CE-3187C9C86E26

16:32:11  NotBefore: 1/10/2017 4:01 PM

16:32:11  NotAfter: 1/10/2018 10:01 PM

16:32:11 Subject: CN=ED346674-0FA1-4272-85CE-3187C9C86E26

16:32:11 Signature matches Public Key

16:32:11 Root Certificate: Subject matches Issuer

16:32:11 Cert Hash(sha1): 7a 5f 2f 31 7a 88 82 fd e5 12 f6 fb 2d 37 46 1f 29 ff 
01 ef

16:32:11 

16:32:11 Certificate "ED346674-0FA1-4272-85CE-3187C9C86E26" already in store.

16:32:11 CertUtil: -addstore command completed successfully.

16:32:11     Task Performs AppX deployment/cleanup in the IDE scenario. 
execution result was failure.

16:32:11 

16:32:11 error 0x80070005: Adding a tile failed with unexpected error.
```

Comment: `if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /b %errorlevel%` can be replaced by `if errorlevel 1 exit /B` which does exactly the same, but a little bit faster. The commands `if` and `exit` do not change current errorlevel (exit/return code) of previous command/application. `if errorlevel 1` means __IF__ exit code of previous command is greater or equal 1 __THEN__ ... Applications usually do not exit with a negative value. Run in a command prompt window `if /?` and see Microsoft support article [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69576).

Answer (score 0):

I can't verify it by myself, but most likely the command line below with missing double quotes is the reason for the failure.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit\appcert.exe" test -appxpackagepath %WORKSPACE%\UWP_0.9.%BUILD_NUMBER%.0_x86_x64_arm.appxbundle -reportoutputpath %WORKSPACE%\wack.xml
```

The value of environment variable `WORKSPACE` referenced twice with `%WORKSPACE%` contains the full path to current workspace folder of the current Jenkins job.

And I suppose this folder path contains 1 or more spaces which requires enclosing both parameter strings in double quotes to be correct passed to `appcert.exe`.

For that case this command line is definitely better:

```
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit\appcert.exe" test -appxpackagepath "%WORKSPACE%\UWP_0.9.%BUILD_NUMBER%.0_x86_x64_arm.appxbundle" -reportoutputpath "%WORKSPACE%\wack.xml"
```

However, I found with a very simple and quick search with my favorite www search engine the page [Error 0x80070005 with Windows App Certification Kit](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/f97805e2-4a7f-4077-8675-197f37cbd47b/) among many others where it is written that error code 0x80070005 literally means "**Access Denied**" on a resource.